# Time complexity and number of calls

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have trouble finding the time complexity of my program and the exact formula to compute the number of calls (represented by the length of the list). Here is my python program that I wrote:

```
from math import *

def calc(n):
    i = n
    li = []
    while i>0:
        j = 0
        li.append(1)
        while j<n:
            li.append(1)
            k = j
            while k<n:
                li.append(1)
                k+=1
            j+=1
        i = floor(i/2)
    return len(li)

for i in range(1, 16):
    print(calc(i))
```

Comment: Looks like n^2 log n to me.  The outer loop is log n, and then you have two inner loops that multiply that by n^2.

Comment: The identation is all wrong

Comment: Sorry, but since I'm new at Stack Overflow I'm not quiet qualified enough to know how to correctly ident my program. Could you help me please ?

Comment: indent fixed.  When most lines need an indent, the secret to an easy fix is to dedent the header line (here the def statement, then select the whole block and hit the code button to add 1 indent to the whole block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For computing time complexity of this program we come from most inner loop.

```
k=j
while k<n:
   li.append(1)
   k+=1
```

Here k iterate one by one forward move start from j to n. That means it run (n-k) time. Now back to the outer loop of this inner loop.

```
j=0
while j<n:
    li.append(1)
    k = j
    //(n-j)
    j+=1
```

Here j also iterate one by one from 0 to n. Total n times. And for every j inner loop iterate n-j.

while j=0 than k=0,1,2,3,....(n-1)   Total n times

while j=1 than k=1,2,3,....(n-1)     Total n-1 times

while j=2 than k=2,3,4,....(n-1)     Total n-2 times

....

....

while j=n-1 than k=(n-1)             Total 1 times

---

Total complexity = 1+2+3+......(n-2)+(n-1)+n

```
             =(n*(n+1))/2;
```

Now the outer loop for i :

```
i=n 
while i>0:
    (n*(n+1))/2;
    i = floor(i/2)
```

Here i start from n and every time divided by 2. We know if it iterate dividing by x than it's complexity will log(base x)(n). Hence, for i the complexity will approximately log(base 2)(n).

Hence the Total time complexity is approximately log(n)*(n*(n+1))/2;

it also can be represented as O(n^2*log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe plotting your total number of calls against your value for n will help:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [i for i in range(1, 16)]
y = [calc(n) for n in x]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, thank you @Marco Breemhaar and how exactly do I calculate the number of calls ?

Comment: As you said yourself, that's represented by the length of the list.

Comment: Sorry, I formulated my question wrong. I wondered if there is a specific formula to calculate the n-th number. Thanks for pointing it out !

Comment: What do you mean by the n-th number? I'm not sure what your function is trying to do...

Comment: When I run my code, I get this sequence for the first 10 numbers: 3, 12, 20, 45, 63, 84, 108, 180, 220, 264. Is there a formula to express this sequence? Example: f(1)=3, f(2)=12, f(10)= 264 and so on.